# Excel - VBA Copy Partial Row and Insert below

Tags: vba, excel

I need help coming up with a small Macro that will let me copy cells A:G for the `ActiveCell` row and Insert it into a new row below the `ActiveCell` row. Currently the code that I have is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row,1),Cells(Active.Row,7)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

But this ends up inserting a new row and copying the `Selection` throughout the row which is not what I want. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Your macro seems to work correctly. Whats the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work except for the `Active.Row` typo. It sounds like you're maybe intending to have an entire row inserted before copying the data. If so, otherwise preserving your method, you could use:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveCell.Offset(1,-ActiveCell.Column+1).Resize(,7)
    .Value = .Offset(-1).Value
End With
```